# Docusign login Bad Request

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

Using the Ruby DocuSign API I keep getting a bad request when executing the login code published on the [Git readme](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client) and only providing the required parameters.
The response I am getting is:

> ETHON: Libcurl initialized
>
> ETHON: performed EASY effective_url=https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token  response_code=400 return_code=ok total_time=0.436539
>
> DocuSign_eSign::ApiError: Bad Request
>
> from /home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/docusign_esign-1.0.0/lib/docusign_esign/api_client.rb:66:in `call_api'
>
> from /home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/docusign_esign-1.0.0/lib/docusign_esign/api_client.rb:410:in `configure_jwt_authorization_flow

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using Admin Consent or User Consent? I would suggest to try hitting APIs directly first through POSTMAN, to be sure that you are following all the steps correctly or not.

Comment: Using POSTMAN I can't get an authentication token. I keep getting an invalid grant error.

Comment: Can you please edit your qs with the end to end steps (with code whereever possible) which you took to generate the accesstoken.

Comment: As described in my question I copied the code from the git readme into a module method and provided the required parameters. When trying to execute the method in rails console I get the bad request response.

Comment: To use JWT, you need to start with User Consent or Admin Consent. For Admin Consent, you need to have an Organization enabled in your DocuSign account, Organization is never enabled by default in any Demo account. Please check [DS Docs[(https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html) for details, code comes into picture once you have done few prerequisite for User or Admin consent.

Comment: I have been able to generate a code using user consent with POSTMAN. The next step of generating an access/authorization token with POSTMAN is when I keep getting an invalid grant error. In any case, I thought that the ruby client would do all this before making an actual api call.

Comment: Once you got userConsent, then you need to generate a JWT for that userId, and your integratorKey. I normally use jwt.io for generating JWT Assertion, and I use epochconverter.com for getting iat and exp values. Once I have JWT assertion then use Postman to generate the AccessToken. But yes, once you have userConsent then Ruby client should generate accesstoken for you, if you correctly provide userId, IntegratorKey, Private Key etc.

Comment: I have never tested Ruby Client, I write my own code for generating JWT and calling REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same issue and I spoke to the person managing the Ruby API SDK:
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client

It seems like what happened for me was that the user consent was missing a scope:

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20**impersonation**&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://docusign.com

Originally I only had signature in my scope, as I was following the example on the documentation page.

Then I changed the user_id from email to the actual key. (It says email or key for the user ID on the admin dashboard but email didn't work for me)